# jQuery ajax, send data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i'm having a problem sending the option selected with ajax.

**Code**:

```
$("#editarConta").on('submit',(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/php/class_conta.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(resultado){
                $("#accountEdit_result").html(resultado);
            }
        });

    }));
```

Sending this data i can't see what option was selected. Is any way i can send this data, plus the selected option like:

```
data: { new FormData(this) , optionSelected: $( "#linguagem_favorita option:selected" ).val() },
```

**My select HTML code**:

```
<select name="linguagem_favorita" id="linguagem_favorita" class="form-control">
```

If i send with my code i get **NULL** when i var_dump the variable

```
var_dump($_POST["linguagem_favorita"]);
```

Comment: What does `new FormData(this)` do?

Comment: send the form values for PHP

Comment: I can deduct that it serialize form to JSON string, but I need to look at the code to answer your question. What is printed for this code: `console.log( $(this).serialize() );` ?

Comment: U wanna see the ajax or php file?

Comment: I don't have a constructor in JS, FormData send ALL values inside the form to php.

Comment: @MaxZoom Learn about FormData: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects There is nothing for the OP to add, it is built in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append to the form data:

```
$("#editarConta").on('submit',(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData(this);
    formData.append("optionSelected", $("#linguagem_favorita option:selected" ).val() );

    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/php/class_conta.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(resultado){
            $("#accountEdit_result").html(resultado);
        }
    });

}));
```